# Quick-overview lists of Dhammas within Buddhism

Tags: reference-request, media, learning-materials, community

This community wiki post is about gathering lists that serve as a ***quick-overview*** of the different Dhammas in Buddhism. We are looking for dhamma-lists from all traditions.

If you have found a list and want to post it please follow the same formating style.

Answer (score 2):

[**Theravada Buddhism**](http://www.insightmeditationcenter.org/books-articles/dhamma-lists/)

Dhamma List that contains an overview of the most essential dhammas in theravada buddhism. They are ordered and downloadable in PDF-format.

In here you will find the different *theravada dhammas*, *pali-to-english translation* of most used words and a quick-guide to *the Tipitaka*.